# Is $1^{1!}+2^{2!}+3^{3!}+\dots n^{n!}$ a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

Is $1^{1!}+2^{2!}+3^{3!}+\dots n^{n!}$ a perfect square?

Obviously, $1$ is a perfect square. When $n=2$, the sum is $5$, which is not a perfect square. When $n=3,4$, the sum is $2\pmod{4}$. For $n=5$, the last 2 digits of the sum is $15$. When $n=6$, the sum is $7\pmod{8}$. When $n=7,8$, the number is either $2,3,7,8\pmod{10}$. But when $n=9$, the sum is $1\pmod{8}$, the sum of digits of divisible by $9$, and the last digit is $9$, but still not a perfect square.

Other than $1$, are there any perfect square in the sequence  $1^{1!}+2^{2!}+3^{3!}+\dots n^{n!}$?

I think  $1^{1!}+2^{2!}+3^{3!}+\dots n^{n!}$ will be a perfect square number if $n\equiv\pm1\pmod{10}$.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused -- your conjecture is that $n \equiv \pm 1 \mod 10$ is sufficient, but you also say that $n=9$ does not yield a perfect square?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hint: $n^{n!}$ is a perfect square (when $n\ge2$). What is the next perfect square after $n^{n!}$? How large is it compared to the quantity in the OP?

Comment: Could you provide another hint or more details? I'm interested in the solution but I'm still not able to make any connection here

Comment: Yeah, im interested in it too. Can you write more the full solution maybe?

Comment: I'll help you work through it. Do you believe that $n^{n!}$ is a perfect square when $n\ge2$? What is the next perfect square after $n^{n!}$?